# How to call multiple column of DataFrame on both axis for plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataFrame has the following column, which shows pressure and corresponding volume measured for different samples, e.g. `s_1p`: pressure for sample-1 & `s1_nv`: corresponding volume for the same sample. I want to show all volume columns on the x-axis and pressure on the y-axis of the same plot (not sub-plot) and legend labelled as the sample number.

```
df=

 s1_p   s1_nv   s9_p    s9_nv   s21_p   s21_nv  s26_p   s26_nv  s32_p   s32_nv  s37_p   s37_nv  s49_p   s49_nv  s52_p   s52_nv  s105_p  s105_nv s118_p  s118_nv
    0   0.977966    0.000544    0.928902    0.000000    1.140129    0.000000    1.002083    0.000000    0.958008    0.000000    1.301460    0.000000    0.964661    0.000000    0.976303    0.001193    1.002914    0.000246    1.008736    0.000129
    1   1.022041    0.001087    0.953850    0.000000    1.175056    0.000153    1.079422    0.000208    0.980461    0.001955    1.328903    0.000000    0.986282    0.000000    1.004578    0.003279    1.034515    0.000246    1.038673    0.000385
    2   1.050316    0.001268    0.984619    0.000000    1.204163    0.000153    1.140961    0.000208    1.012062    0.002557    1.357178    0.000000    1.015388    0.000125    1.031189    0.004621    1.056137    0.000246    1.061127    0.000513
    3   1.082748    0.001268    1.010399    0.000261    1.224953    0.000153    1.249901    0.000208    1.029526    0.002557    1.382958    0.000191    1.033684    0.000125    1.062790    0.004770    1.085243    0.000493    1.094391    0.000513
    4   1.109360    0.001268    1.031189    0.000261    1.247406    0.000153    1.314766    0.000208    1.075264    0.003159    1.407074    0.000381    1.066948    0.000125    1.097717    0.004770    1.136803    0.000493    1.130981    0.000513
    5   1.127655    0.001268    1.056969    0.000261    1.277344    0.000306    1.459465    0.000417    1.130150    0.003460    1.446159    0.000381    1.113518    0.000250    1.138466    0.004919    1.160919    0.000739    1.149277    0.000641
    6   1.160087    0.001268    1.086075    0.000261    1.302292    0.000459    1.629112    0.000624    1.150108    0.003610    1.472771    0.000381    1.140129    0.000250    1.160088    0.005068    1.225784    0.000739    1.177551    0.000898
    7   1.209152    0.001268    1.117676    0.000392    1.328072    0.000459    1.658218    0.000624    1.171730    0.003911    1.514351    0.000571    1.209984    0.000250    1.212479    0.005217    1.293144    0.000739    1.247406    0.000898
    8   1.259048    0.001268    1.151772    0.000392    1.370483    0.000612    1.748863    0.000624    1.249069    0.005114    1.555100    0.000571    1.278175    0.000250    1.270691    0.005217    1.372978    0.000739    1.310608    0.000898
    9   1.283165    0.001268    1.180878    0.000392    1.399590    0.000612    1.920174    0.000624    1.290649    0.005415    1.575890    0.000571    1.297302    0.000375    1.379631    0.005217    1.420380    0.000986    1.334724    0.000898
    10  1.362167    0.001268    1.227448    0.000392    1.426201    0.000612    2.064041    0.000833    1.333893    0.005716    1.602501    0.000761    1.351357    0.000500    1.466949    0.005217    1.592522    0.001232    1.507698    0.001283
    11  1.446991    0.001449    1.278175    0.000392    1.475266    0.000612    2.252815    0.000833    1.434517    0.006919    1.635765    0.000761    1.385452    0.000500    1.636597    0.005664    1.757179    0.001232    1.666534    0.001796
    12  1.473602    0.001630    1.297302    0.000522    1.541794    0.000765    2.432442    0.000833    1.603333    0.010077    1.698967    0.000761    1.518509    0.000625    1.802917    0.005664    1.778801    0.001726    1.698967    0.001796
    13  1.667366    0.001630    1.316429    0.000522    1.639923    0.000765    2.614563    0.000833    1.626617    0.010077    1.790444    0.000761    1.693977    0.000750    1.840340    0.005664    1.800423    0.002218    1.870277    0.002181
    14  1.837845    0.001630    1.344704    0.000652    1.712273    0.000919    2.812485    0.000833    1.809570    0.010679    1.828697    0.000761    1.715599    0.000750    1.972565    0.006111    1.988365    0.002958    2.044083    0.002181
    15  2.042419    0.001630    1.412063    0.000783    1.861130    0.000919    2.984627    0.000833    1.831192    0.010679    1.856972    0.000761    1.876098    0.000750    2.142212    0.006410    2.167160    0.002958    2.083168    0.002438
    16  2.222878    0.001630    1.476929    0.000783    2.029114    0.001531    3.014565    0.001041    2.003334    0.011732    1.964249    0.000951    2.058220    0.001000    2.173813    0.006410    2.209572    0.003204    2.250320    0.002566
    17  2.256142    0.001630    1.497719    0.000913    2.052398    0.001531    3.169243    0.001041    2.026619    0.011882    2.134727    0.000951    2.265290    0.001125    2.325165    0.006708    2.385040    0.003451    2.417473    0.002695
    18  2.422463    0.001630    1.672356    0.001305    2.163834    0.001531    3.354691    0.001041    2.198761    0.013687    2.299385    0.001142    2.439095    0.001125    2.495644    0.007005    2.556351    0.003697    2.449905    0.002695
```

When I used the following code, it does the job.

```
S1_P=df['s1_p']
S1_V=df['s1_nv'] #(similarly for other samples)
plt.plot(S1_P, S1_V, color='r', label='S1')
plt.plot(S9_P, S9_V, color='g', label='S9')
plt.plot(S21_P, S21_V, color='g', label='S21')
```

But problem is that I have to call all the individual columns as **a series** and then again and again for the plot.

```
df.plot(x=["s1_p", 's9_p', 's21_p'] y=["s1_v", 's9_v', 's21_v']) showed error.
```

I want to automate the process so that I don't have to call each individual column for the plot.
Any suggestion to plot the data in a single plot using seaborn or matplotlib

Comment: Did you try the `data` keyword? `plt.plot('s1_p', 's1_v', color='r', label='S1', data=df)`

Comment: For a list, e.g.: `[plt.plot(f's{num}_p', f's{num}_nv', label=f's{num}', data=df) for num in [1, 9, 21]]
`

Comment: Hi @JohanC, Yes, I tried with data keyword, I can get this `plt.plot('s1_p', 's1_v', color='r', label='S1', data=df)` plot for single sample data, but the point is that I want to do for all the sample together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the dataframe you provided, the simplest way I am aware of drawing the plot you want is re-shape the dataframe in a proper way and then plot it.

### Dataframe re-shaping

You need to re-shape your data in a dataframe with 3 columns: `sample`, `pressure` and `volume`. In order to do so, I save data in a new dataframe `DF`:

```
samples = list(set([col.replace('s', '').replace('_p', '').replace('_nv', '') for col in df.columns]))

DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['sample', 'pressure', 'volume'])

for sample in samples:
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df.columns:
        if f's{sample}_' in col:
            df_tmp['sample'] = len(df[col])*[sample]
            if col.endswith('p'):
                df_tmp['pressure'] = df[col]
            else:
                df_tmp['volume'] = df[col]
    DF = DF.append(df_tmp)

DF['sample'] = DF['sample'].astype(int)
DF = DF.sort_values(by = 'sample', ignore_index = True)
DF['sample'] = DF['sample'].astype(str)
```

```
    sample  pressure    volume
0        1  1.127655  0.001268
1        1  0.977966  0.000544
2        1  1.022041  0.001087
3        1  1.050316  0.001268
4        1  1.082748  0.001268
5        1  1.109360  0.001268
6        1  1.160087  0.001268
7        1  1.209152  0.001268
8        1  1.283165  0.001268
9        1  1.259048  0.001268
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')

samples = list(set([col.replace('s', '').replace('_p', '').replace('_nv', '') for col in df.columns]))

DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['sample', 'pressure', 'volume'])

for sample in samples:
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df.columns:
        if f's{sample}_' in col:
            df_tmp['sample'] = len(df[col])*[sample]
            if col.endswith('p'):
                df_tmp['pressure'] = df[col]
            else:
                df_tmp['volume'] = df[col]
    DF = DF.append(df_tmp)

DF['sample'] = DF['sample'].astype(int)
DF = DF.sort_values(by = 'sample', ignore_index = True)
DF['sample'] = DF['sample'].astype(str)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = DF, x = 'volume', y = 'pressure', hue = 'sample')

plt.show()
```

### Plot

Now you can plot your data, for example you can use [**`seaborn.scatterplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = DF, x = 'volume', y = 'pressure', hue = 'sample')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Why plot has only 8 trends while the legend showing 10 samples. This is happening on my real data as well. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's because samples `1` and `118` are perfectly overlapped, as well as samples `9` and `49`. You can check this by plotting: `sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = DF, x = 'volume', y = 'pressure', hue = 'sample', style = 'sample', s = 200, alpha = 0.5)`

Comment: Thanks,  I don't know why 1 & 118  and 9 & 49 are perfectly overlapped.  Data is not the same for all these samples, so there is a slight difference expected.

Comment: I also get an error (while plotting) `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `  when the rows of each sample are not the same. Could you please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: You are right regarding difference expected from sample to sample: there is a bug on my code above, thank you for having catching this. Tomorrow morning I will have a look more in depth on it

Comment: I found and fixed the bug, I changed the if statement `if f's{sample}_' in col:` inside the loop. I updated my answer, now it catches and plots all samples. Have a look at it and let me know if it works for you :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236551/discussion-between-akshahi17-and-zephyr).